# Use '_' in map for string interpolation

Tags: scala

I have a `List[String]`, and I want to quote each element. So I figured I could just do `var.map(s"'$_'")`. But that gives me *error in interpolated string: identifier or block expected*. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use the `_` within a string interpolation?

I'm currently doing `var.map("'" + _ + "'")`, but it seems somewhat verbose and confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PR to make this work wasn't merged because the syntax was considered too radical, too unsettling.

The PR for the same syntax in a pattern context was accepted, however.

There is some discussion at:

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2793

I would have used this syntax at least a handful of times. People like to save an extra arrow. People also don't like the burden of inventing identifiers needlessly. Yes, like `x`.

Answer (score 6):

I would do:

```
var.map(x => s"'$x'")
```

It is decidedly less "verbose and confusing", and probably less confusing than `var.map(s"'$_'")` as well.

Comment: This is currently the usual syntax to avoid `+`. I would probably take issue with "probably less confusing." Taking away punctuation, `v map s"'$_'"`.